# Recursive calculation in Child, Parent, Grand Parent and Great Grand Parent React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

[image: Click Here to see child parent structure]

I have a main component **ParentA** Which has children as **ChildA**, **ChildB**, **ChildC** and **ParentB** And same repeating components inside itself.
So what actually i need, If I made any calculation inside **ChildF** This is instantly reflecting in **ParentC** In Column A, But it also should be Reflecting instantly in **ParentB** and **ParentA** column's A.

Looking forward for response.

Comment: You will have to hoist the child states to the parent component and pass them down. That way you can do all the calculations you need as the data is shared. Alternatively, you can use a global state like Redux or Saga for tracking the state of each component

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution here is to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), in this case to `ParentC`, and have `ParentC` provide the descendant components a way to update `ParentC`'s state, by passing down a setter via props or [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Here's a small example using props:

```js
const {useState} = React;

function ParentC() {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    
    const addOne = () => {
        setCounter(c => c + 1);
    };
    
    const addTwo = () => {
        setCounter(c => c + 2);
    };
    
    return (
        <div>
            <DisplayChild value={counter} />
            <UpdaterChild onAdd={addOne} label="Add One" />
            <UpdaterChild onAdd={addTwo} label="Add Two" />
        </div>
    );
}

function UpdaterChild({onAdd, label}) {
    return (
        <input type="button" value={label} onClick={onAdd} />
    );
}

function DisplayChild({value}) {
    return <div>Value = {value}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<ParentC/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Notice how `counter` is held at the parent level and passed down to the children, along with (where relevant) appropriate setters for them to call.